# Wy is mysqldump producing structure only

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mysql, mysqldump

OS Version: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
MySQL server version: Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 (Ubuntu)

I have been using the following command to produce a data dump:

```
mysqldump -u someuser -psomepassword mydb > /home/mysql_bkp/my_bkp.sql
```

The last good backup I have using this command was 2 weeks ago. Today, when I was using it to produce a backup, it only produced the structure. The only thing I did since was update the server as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
suso apt-get upgrade
```

Any ideas?

## ANSWER:

No problem with disk space. It turns out that the other sysop accidentally erased the DB, so I was only left with nothing but the structure. Of course I wasted several hours before I figured this out.

Comment: do you have enough free space on the disk>

Comment: No problem with disk space. It turns out that the other sysop accidentally erased the DB, so I was only left with nothing but the structure. Of course I wasted several hours before I figured this out.

Comment: Could you add this as an answer?